# ViewModel observe is triggered more than twice while the API is hitting only once

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-viewmodel

The viewmodel observe is triggering up many times(3-4) in a row for the same event in both fragment and activity. Here's the viewmodel code:

```
 userModel.getResponseSuperRegion(countryID)
        userModel.responseSuperRegion.observe(this,
                Observer {
                    if(it!=null) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"Observer ran!!!!")
                        Utils.debugger("FRAG ", "$it")
                        requestResults(countryID, date, spec, it!!.get(0).nameValue, businessUnit)
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Data Not Available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        dismissProgress()
                    }
                })
```

the same type of code i am using for fragment and there too I am receiving the same issue. I have tried by using viewLifecycleOwner but that is also not working out in case of fragments and viewLifecycleOwner is not there for activity so please suggest me some way to get rid of this issue. I have read majority of the similar SO threads but none of them is working.

**Update**: already tried by
userModel.responseSuperRegion.removeObservers(this)

Comment: are you having said fragment in ViewPager ?

Comment: Yes but it is also happening in activity

Comment: Means for the viewmodel observer in the activity

Answer (score 1):

This is working like charm, basically remove the subscribers once the trigger has generated.

```
 userModel.getResponseGrowthSpinner(businessUnitID, isGroup, firstReportTypeId)
    userModel.responseGrowthSpinner.observe(this,
            Observer {
                Utils.debugger("FRAG ", "$it")
                purchase_options_spinner.adapter = GrowthSpinnerAdapter(it)
                userModel.responseGrowthSpinner.removeObservers(this)       //add this line
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

are u calling view model at `oncreate()`?  like

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        //init ViewModel
        UserViewModel userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(UserViewModel.class);
        userModel.getResponseSuperRegion(countryID);
}
```

Edit : 
if you use kotlin change your view model to init function 
change on viewModel

```
class UserModel(val countryID:String):ViewModel(){
  init{
    getResponseSuperRegion(countryID)
  }
  fun getResponseSuperRegion(countryID){
    ...
  }
}
```

then in activity or baseactivity remove this

```
userModel.getResponseSuperRegion(countryID)
```

then change

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of
(this,CustomViewModelFactory("countryID")).get(UserViewmodel::class.java)
```

to passing parameter countryID from activity to viewmodel

Comment: I have a separat BaseActivity class where i have initialized the userViewModel at class level like:
val userModel: UserViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]
    }

Comment: I have other methods too in that UserModel class so can't pass parameter in constructor and the problem seems to be with Observer which is getting called multiple times

Comment: if that you can check if viewmodel has been call or not like if(userModel==null){userModel.getResponseSuperRegion(countryID)}